# How to use textures in opengl? (invalid operation error: 1282)

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I am new to opengl and I am currently trying to tackle textures. I keep getting error 1282 (invalid operation) whenever I call glTextureParameteri(). As far as I can tell, every resource has written this the same way.  This is the code snippet that is giving me trouble.

```
        ImageLoader image("res/Textures/test.bmp");
        GLuint texture;
        glGenTextures(1, &texture);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
        glTextureParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTextureParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image.getPixels());
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

The error code appears on the lines with glTextureParameteri(). What is invalid/ wrong with the way I have done this?

Comment: [Reference manual](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml) lists this function as available only starting from OpenGL4.5. Does the system you are running this program on support it?

Comment: @VTT Yep. I have a gtx 1060 that has been updated somewhat recently and I just check and the program I have written is running in opengl4.6.0 Also, I just checked the older function glTexParameteri() and that does seem to work

Answer (score 2):

The [`glTextureParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexParameter.xhtml) functions take as first argument a texture handle, not a texture target. The parameters you use seem to be for the `glTexParameter` function. These two are not the same, so you can either use the other function or change the parameter.